# Bootstrap - Button being pushed down a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues with my bootstrap code. When I re-size the screen the button is being pushed down outside of the row and container. It seems the container class isn't even being used. Where did I go wrong here? Thank you.

```css
#cta-center {
  line-height: 90px;
}

#cta-bg {
  background: gray;
  height: 90px;
}

.cta p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.btn-primary p {
  color: #000;
  line-height: 34px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="cta-center">
  <div id="cta-bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cold-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="cta">
              <p>Get a FREE Quote NOW</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
              <p>CLICK HERE</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image:
[image: https://s9.postimg.org/mr315w8nj/cta.png]

Comment: You have `cold-md-12`

Comment: Even after changing it to col...It still gets pushed down to the next row